# Error when exporting data to CSV in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm getting an error message when exporting data to CSV. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)
energy <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json" %>% 
  fromJSON
file <- c("C://Users//x////sankeyData.txt")
write.table(energy, file, sep="\t")
```

The error message I'm getting is the following:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 48, 68

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `energy` is a list of two data frames (`nodes` with 48 rows and `links` with 68 rows). If you want to save this list something like this will work:

```
file <- c("C://Users//x////sankeyData.rds")
saveRDS(object = energy, file = file)
```

In case you want two data frames saved then apply function `write.table` twice for each data frame with different file names.